# Why Javascript variable value displays as NaN in emulator? - Android Phonegap

Tags: android, date, cordova, time, alert

### **Problem**

In Android Phonegap project, I can't get the value of variable.

### **JavaScript Code Snippet:**

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var dateandtime = date.trim() + "T" + time.trim() + "+0000";

var dateNew = new Date(dateandtime); 
var difference = dateNew.getTime() - (currentDate.getTime() - 120000); // New - Current - 2 minute

var time1 = difference / 1000;
alert("Seconds : " + time1);
```

### **Result:**

[image: Alert Image]

If any solution for this problem then please share.
Thank you.

Comment: `NaN` defines that the value which you are trying to set in your alert does not a number. Make sure you set the number.

Comment: @GrIsHu Hello Grishma, Please See the Snippet which I have provided. I set `time1` as alert. time1 is number, But I can't get it.

Comment: May be you are getting the double value as you are dividing the `difference` with 1000.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I also try `Math.floor(time1);` `Math.round(time1);` is also not working.

Comment: Still just try to print the value it might be not getting round value.

Comment: I think Problem is in casting

Comment: Try My Code, It will helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Try This :**

```
var currentDate = new Date();

var arrDataOfDate = data1[0].split("-");
var arrDataOfTime = data1[1].split(":");

var year = parseInt(arrDataOfDate[0]);
var month = parseInt(arrDataOfDate[1]);
var day = parseInt(arrDataOfDate[2]);

var hours = parseInt(arrDataOfTime[0]);
var minutes = parseInt(arrDataOfTime[1]);
var seconds = parseInt(arrDataOfTime[2]);

var dateNew = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);

var difference = dateNew.getTime() - (currentDate.getTime() - 120000);

var time1 = parseFloat(difference / 1000);
alert("Seconds : " + parseInt(time1));
```

I think problem in creation of **Date Object**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var time1 = parseFloat(difference) / 1000;
alert("Seconds : " + parseInt(time1));
```

Comment: Give me a date  and time String